# Locate mouse helper in Xubuntu for visually impaired

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, xfce, accessibility

I can't find a `locate pointer` feature (anymore) in Xubuntu.

Is there an Xubuntu 13.10 (XFCE) alternative for the `Show Mouse` Accessibility CCSM plugin for ubuntu?

My mother is slightly visually impaired and has difficulties finding the mouse. Her computer is to old/weak to run Ubuntu/Unity.

**UPDATE**

Still not present in 14.04, but I noticed the feature exists in default Debian: `Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed`, maybe that's GNOME not XFCE.

As I recall correctly it existed in Xubuntu in older versions too, why has this extremely valuable feature been dropped?

Comment: Have you looked into `Settings > Accessibility` within Xfce? See http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/accessibility .

Comment: Yes, first thing I did. But I don't see it there, nor in the screenshots in your linked url. Nor I have found it in Orca.

Comment: Hmm, have you looked into this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13816/need-alternative-to-accessibilitys-locate-pointer-to-visually-highlight-the-m ?

Comment: This is a long-shot, but have you tried `xfce4-eyes-plugin`, as suggested in the linked question above?

Comment: I tried the suggested xfce4-eyes-plugin but IMHO this is just a toy and not a serious solution for visually impaired people.

Comment: I agree, it's a toy. Sorry, can't help more as I have no experience with this. From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility : "If you install the Ubuntu system after booting the Ubuntu Desktop CD with an accessibility option as described above, those features will also be preconfigured to start by default on your newly installed system. 

The most common accessibility tools such as Orca and onBoard are preinstalled on any standard Ubuntu system and are easy to activate." So I guess some packages are missing. See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1119882 .

Answer (score 7):

About the original question: I too am an xfce user and am somewhat visually impaired.
I use the red pointer, but often can't find it in a cluttered desktop. Then I just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> which pulls up a file manager menu box. I don't need it, but it's always placed on the desktop with the cursor at one of its upper corners. Once I've located the cursor, I just left-click away from the file manager menu box, and I'm back in business.
Hope this helps the OP's mother.

Answer (score 1):

Try a new mousetheme with partial transparent background and use an improved high/contrast theme

Mousetheme:
[DMZ with Yellow Background Multisized](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/DMZ+with+Yellow+Background+Multisized?content=164006).

Theme:
[Treepata (improved high/contrast theme)](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Treepata+-+High+contrast?content=151928)

Suggestions have been given here:
[Is there a `Locate pointer` helper in Lubuntu (for visually impaired)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569274/is-there-a-locate-pointer-helper-in-lubuntu-for-visually-impaired)

IMHO this is an acceptable solution that offers an appropriate type of assistance for the visual impaired in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be anything included by default. In Ubuntu, it is the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer` gsettings option, but xfce4 does not have it.

You could theoretically build something yourself using `xdotool` and bind a hotkey to it. [Here](https://github.com/phil294/x11-cursor-locater-example) is an example.